# How to create a list like "Recent apps list" in Android L

Tags: android, user-interface

How to create a list of items like a list of recent apps in androild L :

[image]

Comment: What did you try so far? Show us some code (and effort...) - before we probably can't help you much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty easy:

- Start with a layout for a single item. Create an xml with a toolbar, icon, title, [x] button, etc.
- Create a layout for holding these items. You may start with any layout class you wish - FrameLayout is pretty simple and works well in this case.
- Implement adding items to your container. You may want to use an adapter. In such case check out the sources of ListView or similiar.
- Implement gesture detection. Scrolling is pretty easy, but you may want to handle swipe gestures to easily dismiss items. Check out any of the swipe-to-dimiss libraries for more details.
- Implement layouting. This part is the most difficult. Position of items on screen is a non-linear function of scroll + position in layout. Basically you would like to have a close-to-zero position for items on top of the container and container.getHeight()-item.getHeight() as a position for the item at the bottom. Then you have to find a function which works for you. For me it's something like this:

  ```
  private void layoutChildren() {
      int width = getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
      int height = getHeight() - getPaddingTop() - getPaddingBottom();
      for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
          float topSpace = height - width;
          int y = (int) (topSpace * Math.pow(2, (i * width - scroll) / (float) width));
          float scale = (float) (-Math.pow(2, -y / topSpace / 10.0f) + 19.0f / 10);
          ViewHelper.setTranslationX(getChildAt(i), getPaddingLeft());
          ViewHelper.setTranslationY(getChildAt(i), y + getPaddingTop());
          ViewHelper.setScaleX(getChildAt(i), scale);
          ViewHelper.setScaleY(getChildAt(i), scale);
      }
  }
  ```

For more details and the implementation you can check out my project:

https://github.com/ZieIony/MaterialRecents

Or if you wish to see that in action, it's a part of Carbon library. You can find a sample application with that RecentsList in the widget section:

https://github.com/ZieIony/Carbon

Comment: I tried using the library (MaterialRecents) but I was implementing it in landscape more in which case the cards appearance and specially swiping movement gets kind of reversed (this works fine in vertical orientation). Can you please suggest the changes required?

Comment: @Zielony, This is the same question I asked you.

Comment: And here's the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36622248/horizontal-scrolling-cards-just-like-recent-apps-of-lollipop-in-android/36622804#36622804